# Pulling DatePicker value from CoreData to display with Text("")

Tags: ios, date, swiftui, datepicker

I've gotten all my other textfields and pickers to pull from CoreData and display using Text(""). However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to display the date picked in the date picker using the Text(""). For my other fields I've used this syntax:

Textfields: `Text("\(record.hoursSlept, specifier: "%.2f") Hours Slept")`

Picker: `Text("Mask Type: \(record.maskType ?? "N/A")")`

Toggle: `if (record.smartStartToggle) == false {Text("Smart Start Off").......`

DatePicker: `Text("\(record.todaysDate ?? "date error")")`

The date picker one just gives an error and I've tried a date formatter and that doesn't work either..... HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, where the date is tested for nil value first, then display the String `"date error"` or the String `\(record.todaysDate!)`

```
 Text(record.todaysDate == nil ? "date error" : "\(record.todaysDate!)")
```

instead of: `Text("\(record.todaysDate ?? "date error")")` where you have "date error" that is a `String`, but `record.todaysDate` is a `Date`, and so cannot be compared.